# Making a programmatic iOS UIView fully accessible

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility

I am programmatically building a `UINavigationContoller` for iOS and am having problems making it fully accessible.  In `loadView`  I create the main `UIView` and set it as NOT accessible:

```
    - (void)loadView
    {
    CGRect viewRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIView *tmp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
    [tmp setIsAccessibilityElement:NO];
```

I then add additional `UIViews` that contain just background images and also set those as not accessible. All views and controls are added onto the "tmp" `UIView` created above. Here is a "background" view example:

```
UIImage* microphone = [UIImage imageNamed:@"microphone.jpg"];
    UIView* microphoneView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,viewRect.size.width, microphone.size.height)] autorelease];
    [microphoneView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:microphone]];
    [microphoneView setIsAccessibilityElement:NO];
    [tmp addSubview:microphoneView];
```

Finally I add a `UIButton`, `UILabel` and `UIButtonBarItem`. I add these last so they are on the top of the view hierarchy.  I add accessibility labels and traits to them.  Here is the `UIButton`:

```
self.recordImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"record_button.png"];
self.stopRecordImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"stop_button.png"];
self.recordButton.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraitStartsMediaSession;
self.recordButton = [[UIButton alloc  ] initWithFrame: CGRectMake((viewRect.size.width - recordImage.size.width)/2 , (microphone.size.height + (grayBkg.size.height - recordImage.size.height)/2), recordImage.size.width, recordImage.size.height)];
[self.recordButton setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
[self.recordButton setAccessibilityLabel:  @"toggle recording start"];
[self.recordButton setImage: recordImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.recordButton addTarget: self action:@selector(processButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[tmp addSubview:recordButton];
```

finally

```
....
[self setView:tmp];
[tmp release];
```

I did call `UIAccessibilityPostNotification`(`UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification`, nil); when I push this view onto the stack.

With voiceover on, when the view is displayed I can swipe and give each of my elements (the `UIButtonBarItem`, `UILabel`, and `UIButton`) focus and I can activate them with double tap.  However, VoiceOver speaks no information about the elements.  Testing in the simulator with the Accessibility Inspector shows the labels I have set via aControl.accessibilityLabel = @"the label";

This view is used to record audio.  If I activate the buttons and record the audio and stop recording,  VoiceOver will now speak the labels for the elements when I focus them?  Why is VoiceOver not speaking the information when the view first loads?  Any clues appreciated!

I am testing on an iPad 2 with iOS 4.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This view is being used for audio recording. The problem was that I was setting the AVSession Category to AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord in the viewDidLoad method. This was causing VoiceOver not to speak the view information.   I modified the code to set the category to AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord only when the record button is pushed. And I set it to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord when recording is finished. Here is the thread that explains it fully:  http://lists.apple.com/archives/accessibility-dev/2011/Jul/msg00002.html

Comment: This link no longer seems to show content. Is there an alternate way to get the info or a summary of the details there? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like your view to not be accessible, use:

```
[microphoneView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that property.  However, adding that to the views I do not wanted included in the accessibility hierarchy makes no difference in the behavior - the information about the button is not spoken until at least one has been invokved.